# Need help to partition drive

Tags: partitioning

Ok so im in a little problem...

I need to switch back to windows but i need a drive to put it on and i know nothing about how to partition the drives do you think you guys could help?

The ideal solution would be for me to be able to dual boot between the two.

Comment: please edit your Q to include more details.. what partitions do you have (maybe include a snapshot from some partition manager).. and also do you want a switch back to Windows or a dual-boot with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

- Yes,you can be able to dual boot windows and Ubuntu by installing windows alongside Ubuntu.
- Before installing windows,try to create a seperate primary partition having ntfs filesystem using Gparted Utility in Ubuntu.
- After partitioning,try to make a bootable windows usb on Ubuntu through [winusb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-to-create-a-windows-8-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu).
- Now boot from the windows live usb and then select custom option on installation startup to install windows on the created ntfs partition.

Comment: Can you explain how to create a ntfs file system? @Avinash Raj

Comment: see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/CreatingPartitions